# Convert JSON string into Python object

Tags: json, python-2.7

My string

```
"{u'currency_id': u'USD', u'company_id': u'Supplier1', u'name': u'New9', u'created_by': u'Administrator', u'created_date': u'2018-07-31 03:24:41'}"
```

I know this is not valid JSON.

What I want to do is convert this string into JSON first and then create a python object.

Here's my code.

```
def _decode_list(self, data):
    rv = []
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, unicode):
            item = item.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            item = self._decode_list(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            item = self._decode_dict(item)
        rv.append(item)
    return rv

def _decode_dict(self, data):
    rv = {}
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(key, unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            value = value.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            value = self._decode_list(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = self._decode_dict(value)
        rv[key] = value
    return rv

def execute(self, p):
    print(p)
    obj = json.loads(p, object_hook=self._decode_dict)
    print(obj.name) //error
```

Error

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Question is, How do I convert this JSON into python obj.

Before passing string to json.loads(), I tried replacing single quotes with double quotes. But that didn't help much.

**Update**

@Francisco de Borja Sanchez

That link didn't help much.

```
def execute(self, p):
    p = str(p).replace("'", '"')
    obj = json.loads(p, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
    print(obj.name)
```

gives error

```
Extra data: line 1 column 5 - line 1 column 148 (char 4 - 147)
```

Without single quotes replacement.

```
def execute(self, p):
    obj = json.loads(p, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
    print(obj.name)
```

gives error

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Maybe is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object

Comment: @FranciscodeBorjaSanchez That link didn't help much. I updated my question with findings

Comment: This is a totally valid Python dict already. Why don't you load it directly with `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: @blhsing I tried ast.literal_eval() but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

you can do somthing like

```
import ast

def execute(self, p):
    obj = ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(p))
    print(type(obj)) # <- obj is a dict now
    print(obj['name']) # <- prints object name
```

Comment: prints '<type 'str'>' and error - "string indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: what is your string?

Comment: "{u'currency_id': u'USD', u'company_id': u'Supplier1', u'name': u'New9', u'created_by': u'Administrator', u'created_date': u'2018-07-31 03:24:41'}"

Comment: is this an actual string? or a print of a dict? can you
 print type(p) ?

Comment: print(type(obj)) ----> <type 'str'>

Comment: print(type(p)) ----> <type 'str'>

Comment: something wierd about your string. When I test it with the snippet above it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177086/discussion-between-user1-and-nikos-vita-topiko).

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if this does not answer your problem(I cannot comment yet). Based on the information provided, I saw that you don't get any error up until you execute this function:

```
def execute(self, p):
    obj = json.loads(p, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
    print(obj.name)
```

The error says: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'`
This means that the error comes from printing the value "obj.name".
This means that you HAVE successfully converted your json to a python object.
All that you need now is to figure out how to print the name  (maybe try to use a getName() function or use obj.__name)