# How to access namespace variable with another variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I created a namespace using json data as below, learnt from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920523/2748513)

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import json
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace as Namespace
>>> data = '{"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}'
>>> x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: Namespace(**d))
>>> x.name
'John Smith'
```

But if 'name' is to come from a variable, how can I access it?

```
>>> foo='name'
>>> x.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>>
```

Comment: If you want to look the values up by name like this, why aren't you just using a dict (the default) instead of a `SimpleNamespace`?

Comment: @abarnet, yes, I will do so, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `getattr` function:

```
getattr(x, foo)
```

would work as `x.name` when `foo = 'name'`.