# How to load JSON file and assign a value from this JSON to a local variable in Python code?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file (`config.json`) which looks like this:

```
{
  "name":"Ram"
}
```

And a script looks like this:

```
f=open('config.json',)
name=json.load(f) 
print(name)
```

Then, how to assign the local variable (i.e., `name)` into Python code?

Comment: you've got a bad character in your json file.  that additional back-tick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON data into a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object)

Answer (score 0):

You would treat it like any other dictionary. `myDictionary[myKey]` would equal `myValue` for a JSON like `{myKey: myValue}`. Your code should look like this:

```
f=open('config.json',)
jsonF=json.load(f)
name = jsonF["name"] #THIS is how to get the value from a key in a dictionary
print(name)
```