# how to isolate part of json in python?

Tags: python, json, discord

hi i am using api in my code that outputs in json format and it looks like this

```
{"rates":{"CZK":25.738},"base":"EUR","date":"2021-02-09"}
```

i want only the CZK part so 25.738 as output

i had tried this

```
def get_kurz():
    res = requests.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=CZK')
    kurz = json.loads(res.text)
    result = (kurz['CZK'])
    return(result)
```

but that didnt work closest i could get it to work was

```
def get_kurz():
    res = requests.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=CZK')
    kurz = json.loads(res.text)
    result = (kurz['rates'])
    return(result)
```

and that outputs

```
{'CZK': 25.738}
```

Comment: `kurz['rates']['CZK']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dictionary object, you can use access the nested elements by using indexing multiple times.

So, for your dictionary object:

```
out = {"rates":{"CZK":25.738},"base":"EUR","date":"2021-02-09"}
```

If you want the value of `CZK` key then you can directly use:

```
res = out["rates"]["CZK"]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Unknown structure Approach

Assuming you only know the desired key name and nothing else you can follow this approach.

```
def find_key(data, key_name):
    for k,v in data.items():
        if k==key_name:
            print(k)
            break
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            find_key(data[k], key_name)
        else:
            continue
```

This will look in the dictionary for your key, no matter how deep it is placed.

#### known structure Approach

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882054/10269515)

`SimpleNamespace` and `object_hook` are of great value.