# Most effective way to parse JSON Objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to access a specific value within a JSON object, I am successfully doing so using the Try / except statement.

As I am still learning Python, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of achieving this. I often find that for different sets of JSON data the key / value pair moves, and I have to change the index value manually in my code from [0] [1] [2] or [3]

JSON data:

```
{
 "notifications": [
  {
   "timestamp": "1619847600000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "NME39488200",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet1",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "alignmentErrors": {
     "key": "alignmentErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "fcsErrors": {
     "key": "fcsErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "frameTooLongs": {
     "key": "frameTooLongs",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "frameTooShorts": {
     "key": "frameTooShorts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "inErrors": {
     "key": "inErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "outDiscards": {
     "key": "outDiscards",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "outErrors": {
     "key": "outErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "symbolErrors": {
     "key": "symbolErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "timestamp": "1622629140000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "NME39488200",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet11",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "inMulticastPkts": {
     "key": "inMulticastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0.03333333333333334
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0.1
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0.047140452079103175
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "inOctets": {
     "key": "inOctets",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 269348.4166666667
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 341898.5
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 223613.3
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 45132.897905054306
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "inUcastPkts": {
     "key": "inUcastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 300.3333333333333
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 364
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 258.8
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 44.179847089921985
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "outMulticastPkts": {
     "key": "outMulticastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0.03333333333333334
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0.1
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0.047140452079103175
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "outOctets": {
     "key": "outOctets",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 28700.35
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 42799.9
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 17571.2
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 9737.234046475074
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "outUcastPkts": {
     "key": "outUcastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 196.13333333333333
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 237
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 164.4
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 28.93957305989306
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "timestamp": "1620649440000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "NME39488200",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet11",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "inDiscards": {
     "key": "inDiscards",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "timestamp": "1621745580000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "JPE13031399",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet11",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "inBroadcastPkts": {
     "key": "inBroadcastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "outBroadcastPkts": {
     "key": "outBroadcastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I am taking the JSON data from multiple URLs. The code I am using to extract the value 'Avg' from the Key: 'InDiscards'  or 'OutDiscards' is as follows:

```
for url in URLs:
    JSONdata = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False).json()
    JSONkey = JSONdata["notifications"]
    name = JSONkey[0]["path_elements"][1]
    interface = JSONkey[0]["path_elements"][5]
    try:
        outDiscards = JSONkey[0]["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
    except KeyError:
        outDiscards = JSONkey[2]["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
    try:
        inDiscards = JSONkey[0]["updates"]["inDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
    except KeyError:
        inDiscards = JSONkey[2]["updates"]["inDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
```

My understanding here is that we check index [0] for the avg value of OutDiscards (or InDiscards) , if we fail to find a value, we then check index [2] , however surely there must be a better way of achieving this given that sometimes the index may be 1/3/4/5 etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON data into a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend searching with a for loop.

First initialize your variables, I use `None` so I can later determine if my search routine found something

```
outDiscards = None
inDiscards = None
```

Then iterate over all elements in the notifications list

```
for notification in JSONdata["notifications"]:
```

only try to access the value when it hasn't been found yet

```
    if outDiscards is None:
```

try to to access the value and ignore the KeyError

```
        try:
            outDiscards = notification["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    if inDiscards is None:
        try:
            inDiscards = notification["updates"]["inDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

after the search routine there should be values in outDiscards and inDiscards, you can test for that with `if outDiscards is not None`

```
print(outDiscards)
print(inDiscards)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, however i do not understand why and nor could i come to the solution myself, would it be possible to explain why this works?

Comment: what explanation do you need? should i clarify for notification in JSONdata["notifications"] ?

Comment: Regarding the = none, and then looping on that variable

Comment: i edited my answer to clarify