# Map JSON file into Object python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to map a json file to a python object based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object) solution.
The code I tried to write is the following:

```
from json import loads
from collections import namedtuple
from os import path

class CamConfigurator:
    with open(path.join('utility', 'cam', 'configurator.json')) as __configFile:
        __configurator = loads(
            __configFile,
            object_hook=lambda dictonary: namedtuple(
                'X', dictonary.keys()
            )(*dictonary.values())
        )
    camIndex = __configurator.availableCams[-1]
    pathToSnapshots = __configurator.pathToSnapshots
```

The error that came out is the following:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0):

Add `.read()` to the first `loads` input:

```
from json import loads
from collections import namedtuple
from os import path


class CamConfigurator:
    with open(path.join('utility', 'cam', 'configurator.json')) as __configFile:
        __configurator = loads(
            __configFile.read(), # <- there
            object_hook=lambda dictonary: namedtuple(
                'X', dictonary.keys()
            )(*dictonary.values())
        )
    camIndex = __configurator.availableCams[-1]
    pathToSnapshots = __configurator.pathToSnapshots
```