best way to create serializable data model
somewhat inexperienced in python.  I am coming from C# world, and I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to create a data structure in python that:

can have empty fields (None)
can have default values assigned to some fields
can have aliases assigned to fields that would be used during serialization

to clarify:  for example in C# I can do something like this:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class MyDataClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data Label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data Value")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data Description")]
    public MyDataDefinition definiton { get; set; }

    public MyDataClass
    {
        this.label = "Default Label";
    }
}

with this class, i can create instance with only one field pre-populated, and populate the rest of the data structure at will, and then serialize it to JSON with aliased field names as decorated.
In python, i experimented with several packages, but every time i end up with super complex implementation that doesn't hit all of the requirements.  I MUST be missing something very fundamental, because it seems like such a simple and common use case.
how would you implement something like this in most "pythonic" way?

What do you mean by "empty"? Would None work? (null in JSON.) I don't know C# myself. Could you show some example JSON output?

Yes. "None" is appropriate, and what i meant.

@wjandrea something like this:  {
"Data Label":"Default Label",
"Data Value":null,
"Data Description":
{
"f1":1, "f2":"2"
}
}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object mentions https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle but the accepted solution recommending from types import SimpleNamespace seems to be very promising?

OK, I worked on the problem a little, but it's not clear what you mean by "best", and where you haven't actually found a working solution yet, you should just ask how to do it, without getting into "best practices". Make sure to be specific.

Please also add the expected output into the question

Are you aware of dataclasses? Have you read this question? How to make a class JSON serializable?

Hard to say what is "best practice", I personally would say that just working with dictionaries is very common unless you have a good reason to define a class instead (limitation: no default values, no aliases). If that works for you depends on how you intend to use the data. If you have a dictionary, serializing it is just
import json

record = { 
    "Data Label": "Default Label",
    "Data Value": None, 
    "Data Description": {
        "f1": 1, 
        "f2":"2"
    }
}
with open("my_record.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(record, f)

And reading it would be
import json

with open("my_record.json", "r") as f:
    record = json.load(f)

If you're coming from a language that follows OO principles to a T it might look weird to handle data without a class to serve as an interface. But often enough it's just fine.
If it turns out that it isn't, and you really want to have some kind of schema that tells you what your data looks like / helps your IDE to figure out auto-completion, you can add a TypedDict definition to the existing code (new limitation: only valid python variable names can be keys):
from typing import TypedDict, cast
import json

class MyDataContainer(TypedDict):
    label: str
    value: str | None
    definiton: "MyDataDefinition"

class MyDataDefinition(TypedDict):
    f1: int
    f2: str

with open("my_record.json", "r") as f:
    record = cast(MyDataContainer, json.load(f))

record[  # at this point your IDE should hint "label", "value", or "definiton"

Note: The cast doesn't do anything, it just asserts the type to tooling like your IDE. If you want actual run-time checks against the data you're loading, you need to install third-party libraries like typeguard. First, ask yourself though - is there actually value to this, or are you performing this merely to "do things the right way"?

If you can't work with the limitations of dictionaries that I outlined, I'd recommend to go with pydantic. It supports serializing to / deseralizing from json, aliases, defaults, and many many more things:
import pydantic

class MyDataContainer(pydantic.BaseModel):
    label: str = pydantic.Field("Default Label", alias="Data Label")
    value: str | None = pydantic.Field(alias="Data Value")
    definiton: "MyDataDefinition" = pydantic.Field(alias="Data Description")

class MyDataDefinition(pydantic.BaseModel):
    f1: int
    f2: str

with open("my_record.json", "r") as f:
    record = MyDataContainer(**json.load(f))
    # pydantic would have complained if the json didn't comply

print(record.label)  # prints: "Default Label"
print(record.model_dump_json(indent=2))
# prints:
# {
#   "Data Label": "Default Label", 
#   "Data Value": null, 
#   "Data Description": { 
#     "f1": 1, 
#     "f2": "2" 
#   } 
# }


Nice! Thanks for the answer @Arne
What do you mean by "unless you have a good reason to define a class instead"? can you show an example please?

a custom class as a data container for something json-able is more complex than a dictionary, so you should only chose it if you can make use of the additional features they provide. if you have full control over the data and only run the program that consumes it interactively, I'd just use dictionaries. if you e.g. don't trust the data (enforce runtime assertions on types and values), can't control its shape (create aliases), or the code runs on a server (meaningful error messages and recovery), all of those things are imo easier with a class

@EdenRefaelov is that enough of an example, or were you asking for something more concrete?
