# How to make a class JSON serializable for usage in Django session

Tags: python, json, django, session, serialization

I try to store in Django session the following pretty much arbitrary class:

```
class QuizInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_active_question = INVALID_PQA_ID  # integer
        self.sequence = []
```

In turn, each item of `QuizInfo.sequence` list is an instance of `AnsweredQuestion`:

```
class AnsweredQuestion:
    def __init__(self, i_question, i_answer):
        self.i_question = i_question
        self.i_answer = i_answer
```

I try to store such a data structure in `HttpRequest.session` like the following:

```
qi = QuizInfo()
qi.i_active_question = 5  # e.g.
qi.sequence.append(AnsweredQuestion(1, 2))  # e.g.
qi.sequence.append(AnsweredQuestion(3, 4))  # e.g.
quiz_id = 7  # e.g.
request.session['quiz_infos'] = {quiz_id : qi}
```

So `request.session['quiz_infos']` is a dictionary of `int` keys and `QuizInfo` values.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  93.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py" in process_response
  58.                             request.session.save()

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in save
  83.         obj = self.create_model_instance(data)

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in create_model_instance
  70.             session_data=self.encode(data),

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in encode
  96.         serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)

File "C:\Users\Sarge\Envs\PqaWeb1\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py" in dumps
  87.         return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')

File "c:\programs\python37\Lib\json\__init__.py" in dumps
  238.         **kw).encode(obj)

File "c:\programs\python37\Lib\json\encoder.py" in encode
  199.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

File "c:\programs\python37\Lib\json\encoder.py" in iterencode
  257.         return _iterencode(o, 0)

File "c:\programs\python37\Lib\json\encoder.py" in default
  179.         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: Object of type QuizInfo is not JSON serializable
```

How to make the data structure JSON-serializable?

I saw the other questions, however, the answers there mostly suggest to implement a method to pass as a parameter. But where to do this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Use `__dict__` to change that into a dictionary. In your case though you have nested objects which also needs to be converted to dictionaries. This can be found in jsbueno answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967905/3140312). Basically you have to iterate over your object to check for nested objects like so,

```
def my_dict(obj):
   if not  hasattr(obj,"__dict__"):
       return obj
   result = {}
   for key, val in obj.__dict__.items():
       if key.startswith("_"):
           continue
       element = []
       if isinstance(val, list):
           for item in val:
               element.append(my_dict(item))
       else:
           element = my_dict(val)
       result[key] = element
   return result
```

Edit:

Then you can dump the result to a string like so,

```
import json

json.dumps(result)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to deserialize such structure then?

Comment: Use json.dumps(result) will give you a string back.

Answer (score 0):

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757022/how-do-you-serialize-a-model-instance-in-django)** is a possible solution.

Django's serializers are handy, when it comes to serializing/deserializing data.

You might throw an eye to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/) as well. 
Check out also [deserialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data).