# Is there a "shortcut" to declare a single object as in javascript?

Tags: python, class, object

In javascript, we have this object declaration:

```
var object = {property1:1,property2:1 }
```

In python, the traditional way we do that:

```
class my_cls:
  def __init__(self):
    self.property1=1
    self.property2=1
object = my_cls()
```

is there a shortcut in python to declare an object?

Comment: Are you looking for a dictionary which has a very similar syntax to the Javascript object?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528932/how-to-create-inline-objects-with-properties-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285048/is-there-a-shorthand-initializer-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640806/javascript-like-object-in-python-standard-library) at least one of them should answer your question.