# metaclassing, defining __init__ to pass attributes for the instances (not for the class) using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, metaclass, keyword-argument

Similarly [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2466191/832621) I would like to pass the attributes from a dictionary to an instance of a class, but creating the class using `type`, like this:

```
attrs = { 'name': 'Oscar', 'lastName': 'Reyes', 'age':32 }

e = type('Employee', (object,),attrs)()
```

But when I do this the attributes are belonging to the class, not only to the instance. If I create two instances using:

```
e = type('Employee', (object,), attrs)()
f = type('Employee', (object,), attrs)()
```

They will actually be two different classes.

I wanted to create a class that accepts `**kwargs` and `*args` in `__init__()`, like:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

using `type()`. So that:

```
MyClass = type('Employee', (object,), {})
```

Would allow:

```
e = MyClass( **kwargs )
```

Comment: from a PEP8 perspective, I would probably do something like `MyClass = type(...)` rather than `my_class = type(...)` (but of course you're free to do whatever you'd like)

Comment: thank you... very important! I updated the question!

Comment: You are probably better off using a `namedtuple`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- That depends on whether he wants his Employees to be able to age :-P (or change their names)

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, just mentioning options.

Comment: Multiple options are always good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem.  You just need to write the function and include it in the dictionary that you pass to `type` under the key `'__init__'`

```
def func(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.args = args
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self,k,v)

MyClass = type('Employee',(object,),{'__init__':func})
e = MyClass(name='john')
print (e.name) #'john'
```

You can even "delete" `func` when you're done creating the class if it makes you feel better about keeping your namespace clear:

```
MyClass = type('Employee',(object,),{'__init__':func})
#clean up, clean up, everybody everywhere, clean up clean up, everybody do your share ...
del func
```

Comment: The for-loop can be simplified to `vars(self).update(kwargs)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- In a vast majority of the cases yes.  It can't be simplified if the class has `__slots__` though.  But the advantage there is that you could even do that with a `lambda` function:  `{'__init__':lambda self,**kwargs:vars(self).update(kwargs)}`