# The reason for not able to access my object item

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I am creating a class and setting some properties. And I am referencing dictionary as a class object. But not able to access the second element of the object.

I tried to google the problem but it does not specify the cause of my problem.

```
data = {
'a': {
'vsdf': 'asfas',
'nfgn': 'aser',
'aser': 'rtydf'
},
'b': ['ndfg', 'ndf', 'safd']
}

My class looks something like this:
    def __init__(self, meta):
        self.meta = meta

and when i create the object of this class like this:

request = Request(data)

and try to print the request['b'] it shows the error "'Request' object is not subscriptable"
```

Actual result should be like :
['', '', '']

but it shows:
'Request' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have given, the `data` dictionary will be stored in the `meta` instance variable. You'll need to access it by first accessing that variable, i.e. `request.meta['b']`.

In order to get it to act the way you want, you'll need to loop through the dict passed in to `__init__` and set each variable individually. Take a look at this answer for how to do that: [Set attributes from dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466191/set-attributes-from-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: yeah i did and it worked but i didnt get the reason for that?

Comment: Basically, python object attributes are not a dictionary like they are in something like perl (even though behind the scenes they are implemented as a dictionary). You can't set them wholesale in one operation. As far as I can find myself, self.meta has no special meaning in python, so you're just setting an attribute called "meta" on your object to a copy of the "data" dictionary you passed in.