# Yielding a dictionary containing an object's attributes in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a piece of code that will dump all attributes of a given class instance to a dictionary so that I can change them without changing the source object. Is there a method for doing this, or perhaps a built-in dictionary I can copy and access?

What I'm really doing is making a special class that copies the actual attributes (and their corresponding values) from instances of varying other classes. Basically it would mimic any instance of any class.

For example, object x has attributes x.name and x.number, "Joe" and 7, respectively. I want my new object mimic, object y, to copy the attributes so that y now has attributes y.name and y.number, "Joe" and 7.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** *I found what I was looking for shortly after posting this!*

[Python dictionary from an object's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

That's pretty much all I needed to know.

Comment: To clarify, before y "mimics" x, it does not even have the attributes name or number. My dilemma is not simply the transfer of attribute values, but the attributes themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python dictionary from an object's fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a `__getattr__()` (or `__getattribute__()`) method on your "mimic" object that does this only when an attribute is requested, rather than copying the attributes? Among other benefits, this will keep properties as executable code (rather than copying their return value) and will work even if a new attribute is added to the mimicked object after you create the mimic object. (Also, I would call it a wrapper or proxy object rather than a mimic.)  Something like:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__wrapped__ = obj
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.__wrapped__, key)

l = [3, 2, 1]
w = Wrapper(l)
print w.index(2)   # calls through to l.index()
```

Comment: That's another novel approach the OP can take, yes. It has its benefits too. But so does copying the "mimicked" object's `__dict__`; for example, if the semantic of the "Mimic" is to be a snapshot of the "mimicked" object at the time of "mimicking." Just an observation.

Comment: Yeah, the snapshot idea crossed my mind. But I think it would be better to just copy the object in that case, if possible.

Comment: The snapshot is actually what I was looking to make. This is part of an A.I. system in a game where characters have the capacity to remember another's state the last time they met. I save a "snapshot" in one person's mind as the other leaves; the first method has been working wonderfully for me.

Answer (score 1):

Very object has a `__dict__` attribute that maps names (variables) to the values they are bound to. Muck around with that.

```
>>> class MyObj(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...             self.x = x
...             self.y = y
...
>>> foo = MyObj('Joe', 7)
>>> foo.x
'Joe'
>>> foo.y
7
>>> foo.__dict__
{'y': 7, 'x': 'Joe'}
>>> class Mimic(object):
...     def __init__(self, obj):
...             self.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__)
...
>>> m = Mimic(foo)
>>> m.x
'Joe'
>>> m.y
7
>>> print m.__dict__
{'y': 7, 'x': 'Joe'}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will do; just noticed a similar answer seconds ago.