# Is there a way to get a view of several lists/variables as a list like thing in python

Tags: python, view, abstraction

I have several variables like:

```
class X(object):
    ...

class XY(X):
    ...

class XZ(X):
    ...

class XA(X):
    ...

y=XY()
z=[XZ(i) for i in range(1,10)]
a=[XA(i) for i in range(1,10)]
```

I would like to have a listlike view(including iteration and length) of the different variable y and the variables inside z and a.

this is for the sake of convenience w/out any worries about performance.
I could just do

```
view = [self.y] + self.z + self.a
```

each time but that seems to be breaking the DRY principle.

Edit: to clarify that this isn't about taking the instance variables of a class. I just want a view class, probably implementing a list like interface that forwards to other variables.
Or would it be better to make a closure that returns a view list when you call it(since I don't care about performance). Which is simpler/more pythonic/a better idea? How would I implement a list like forwarding class?., ect.

Comment: Do you mean [`C.__dict__`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/62680/78845)?

Comment: what do you need exactly ? a list of the members of your C object ? or a list of all the instances created ?

Comment: Could you clarify on your meaning of "listlike"? The example implies that a list variable, `self.view = [self.y, self.z, self.a]` would be appropriate, and that `class C` would just need to return `self.view` for `__repr__`, `__str__`, or `__unicode__`.

Comment: z and a are lists thats why its view = [self.y] + self.z + self.a not self.view = [self.y, self.z, self.a]

Comment: but if z or a change then it won't have the right view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to "chain" the iterators of `self.z` and `self.a` and add `self.y` to that. Perhaps this does what you want:

```
import itertools
itertools.chain(self.a, self.z, [self.y])
```

The cleanest would probably be to implement it like this:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, y, z, a):
        # ...

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain(self.a, self.z, [self.y])
```

Comment: Maybe passing in *args to init                                            self.args=args return itertools.chain(*self.args) ?

Comment: To make it more general? what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

class X:

```
def __init__ (self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
```

x = X(1,2,3)
print x.**dict**