# CSV reading into a dictionary

Tags: python, class, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to make the program read the CSV file ("airports.csv") and save it into the dictionary, where by I can enter the key in and this will call the airport objects associated with this key.

When I try to print the whole list to make sure it is working it does print the key but prints`{'GKA: <__main__.Airport object as 0x02E92570>}'`

As the question is based around using the dictionary objects and not lists, could you explain where I am going wrong. I may have mixed some of it up and went the wrong way about it as I have always made dictionaries with lists and not objects.

I have attached the CSV file and the tutorial.

If anybody could show me how to properly call a object in a dictionary. Thanks

```
    import csv
    class Airport:

        def __init__(self, idx=-1, airportname='', cityname='', countryname='', code3='',
        code4='',lat=0,long=0, altitude=0,timezone='',DST='',Tz=''):

            self.idx=idx
            self.airportname=airportname
            self.cityname=cityname
            self.countryname=countryname
            self.code3=code3
            self.code4=code4
            self.lat=lat
            self.long=long
            self.lat=lat
            self.altitude=altitude
            self.timezone=timezone
            self.DST=DST
            self.Tz=Tz

        def dictairportChosen(self,filename):

            self.__airportDict={}

            f=open(filename, encoding="utf8")
            csvreader = csv.reader(f)

            for idx, airportname, cityname, countryname, code3, code4, lat, long, altitude, timezone, DST, TZ,  in csvreader:
                airport=Airport(idx, airportname, cityname, countryname, code3, code4, lat, long, altitude, timezone, DST, TZ)
                self.__airportDict[code3]=airport
                print(self.__airportDict)


    aAirportChosen=Airport()
    aAirportChosen.dictairportChosen("airports.csv")
```

The this is a snippet of the CSV file:

```
    1,"Goroka","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689,145.391881,5282,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
    2,"Madang","Madang","Papua New Guinea","MAG","AYMD",-5.207083,145.7887,20,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
    3,"Mount Hagen","Mount Hagen","Papua New Guinea","HGU","AYMH",-5.826789,144.295861,5388,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
    4,"Nadzab","Nadzab","Papua New Guinea","LAE","AYNZ",-6.569828,146.726242,239,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
    5,"Port Moresby Jacksons Intl","Port Moresby","Papua New Guinea","POM","AYPY",-9.443383,147.22005,146,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
    6,"Wewak Intl","Wewak","Papua New Guinea","WWK","AYWK",-3.583828,143.669186,19,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
    7,"Narsarsuaq","Narssarssuaq","Greenland","UAK","BGBW",61.160517,-45.425978,112,-3,"E","America/Godthab"
    8,"Nuuk","Godthaab","Greenland","GOH","BGGH",64.190922,-51.678064,283,-3,"E","America/Godthab"
```

The question of the actual tutorial is:
2.
Write
code
to
read
from
the
csv
and
create
a
dictionary
of
airport
objects
Replace
the
lists
in
the
dictionary
with
airport
objects.
You
should
end
up
with
a
dictionary
that
has
the
airport
code
as
a
key
and
an
airport
object
as
the
lookup
value
allowing
the
code
below
to
run:

```
airportLookupDict={‘DUB’, airport(….),‘LHR’, airport(….)}
myairport=airportLookupDict.get(‘DUB’)
print(myairport.name)
outputs:
DUBLIN
```

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong? You have a dictionary where the key is the airport's code and the value is the `Airport` instance - what were you expecting?

Comment: That was from when i was attempting to have the dictionary in it's own class. Changed it there and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try

`self.__airportDict[code3]=airport.__dict__`

from [Python dictionary from an object's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It works as expected in the question. If you want to access individual elements of the list just add the entity name to the list as follows:

```
    for keys, values in self.__airportDict.items():
        print keys
        print values.airportname
```