# Django Rest Framework Response is not JSON serializable error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following custom exception handler in Django REST framework.

```
class ErrorMessage:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

def insta_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = {}

    if isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        response['success'] = False
        response['data'] = ErrorMessage("Validation error")

    return Response(response)
```

I want a JSON output as shown below

```
"success":false,
"data":{ "message" : "Validation error" }
```

But I get the error `TypeError: Object of type 'ErrorMessage' is not JSON serializable`. Why is a class as simple as `ErrorMessage` above not JSON serializable? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are assigning `ErrorMessage` object to `response['data']`. Class objects can't magically change to python dict. Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields 
For converting python class objects to dict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not serializable because it is an `object`, it should be `dict`, `list` or plain value. But you can easily fix your problem by using magic property `__dict__`

```
def insta_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = {}

    if isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        response['success'] = False
        # like this
        response['data'] = ErrorMessage("Validation error").__dict__

    return Response(response)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think more generic way would be to create a serializer for serializing the error message object:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ErrorMessageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    message = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Then you can do:

```
def insta_exception_handler(exc, context):
    ...
    serializer = ErrorMessageSerializer(ErrorMessage("Validation error"))
    response["data"] = serializer.data
    ...
```