# Converting a list of objects to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I convert a list of objects to a pandas dataframe?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.year = 0
        self.salary = 0
```

For example below works but I want to have a list of person classes instead

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charles', 'David', 'Eric'],
    'year': [2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017],
    'salary': [40000, 24000, 31000, 20000, 30000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Acme', 'Acme', 'Bilbao', 'Bilbao', 'Bilbao'])

print(df)
```

Comment: Like this? question is unclear I think:  `data = {'persons': [Person() for _ in range(5)]}`

Comment: Use a list comprehension? `data = [{'name': person.name, 'year': person.year, 'salary': person.salary} for person in person_list]`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a list of person objects and I want to create a dataframe from that such that the data frames columns are the person's attributes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sort of a combination of [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/ayhan)'s suggestion and what you seem to want -- you can add a method to your Person class that transforms it into something that fits the Pandas DataFrame constructor.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name='', year=0, salary=0):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.salary = salary

    def as_dict(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'year': self.year, 'salary': self.salary}

person1 = Person('john', 2017, 100)
person2 = Person('smith', 2016, 200)
person3 = Person('roger', 2016, 500)

person_list = [person1, person2, person3]

df = pd.DataFrame([x.as_dict() for x in person_list])

print(df)

    name    salary  year
0   john    100     2017
1   smith   200     2016
2   roger   500     2016
```

Comment: Why are the column orders different? It should be:

Comment: how do you set the column orders? The name should be the first column, year should be in the middle and salary last

Comment: pass the ````columns```` arg to the constructor: ````df=pd.DataFrame([x.as_dict() for x in person_list], columns=['name', 'year', 'salary'])````

Comment: also, for completeness, you could use the built-in python ````vars```` function instead of defining ````as_dict````: [vars(x) for x in person_list].

Comment: as_dict() does pretty much the same as __dict__ so `pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in person_list])` is another option (well, in the Python version I tried)

Comment: @im281 the column order has nothing to do with the order in which the dictionary was constructed. dict is a hashing structure so the order is determined internally by its hash function implementation. one should not expect any kind of order at the surface.

Comment: `vars(x)` instead of `x.__dict__` is even more pythonic, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a pandas dataframe from any list by using `vars`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([vars(d) for d in data])
```

This works, because `vars` returns all properties of all objects within your list. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should modify your `__init__()`, since your version just sets every attribute of any `Person` object to default values and does not allow for the user setting them.

You can then use the `zip()` function to create triples of the values in your `data` dictionary and then use those to create `Person` instances

```
import pandas as pd

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name='', year=0, salary=0):
         self.name = name
         self.year = year
         self.salary = salary

data = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charles', 'David', 'Eric'],
        'year': [2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017],
        'salary': [40000, 24000, 31000, 20000, 30000]}

foo = [Person(name, year, salary) for name, year, salary in zip(data['name'], data['year'], data['salary'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(foo, index=['Acme']*2 + ['Bilbao']*3, columns=['Person'])

first_person = df['Person'].iloc[0]
print(first_person.name, first_person.year, first_person.salary)
```

Output:

```
Alice 2017 40000
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

This will take all the (first level) attributes and makes them into a dictionary that can be loaded directly into a Pandas DataFrame, which is what I thought OP was looking for and this avoids having to change the class.

the `not attr.starswith("_")` is there to avoid loading the private attributes into the Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name='', year=0, salary=0):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.salary = salary

person1 = Person('john', 2017, 100)
person2 = Person('smith', 2016, 200)
person3 = Person('roger', 2016, 500)

person_list = [person1, person2, person3]

data = [{attr: getattr(p,attr) for attr in dir(p) if not attr.startswith('_')} for p in person_list ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

    name  salary  year
0   john     100  2017
1  smith     200  2016
2  roger     500  2016
```