# Converting a python object with properties to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cython

I would like to know how to convert a python object from a dictionary (using python3 btw). I realize that this question has been asked (and answered) already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)). However, in my case the object is given entirely in terms of `@property` values, for example:

```
class Test: 
    @property  
    def value(self): 
        return 1.0
```

Regarding conversion to a dictionary: The `__dict__`                           dictionary of the `Test` class is empty, and consequently, the `vars` 
function does not work as expected:

```
>>> vars(Test()) 
{}
```

Still, I can use `gettattr(Test(), 'value')`, to obtain `1.0`, so
the value is present.

Note: The reason I am coming up with this apparently contrived example is that I am trying to convert a cython `cdef class` (containing parameters) to a dictionary. The recommended way to wrap c structures with properties using cython is indeed based on [properties](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#properties).

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to re-implement serialization, which is a difficult problem with plenty of corner cases, but one that has been largely solved.  Why not use pickle?  Otherwise you can try some `getattr`+`dir` solution, but you cannot easily go beyond "what all the values were and function with no arguments returned at time X"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could abuse that:

```py
In [10]: type(Test().__class__.__dict__['value']) is property                   
Out[10]: True
```

So you check the class of the object and if it has attribute of type `property`.

Here is how I would do it:

```py
t = Test() 
dictionary = {attr_name: getattr(t, attr_name)  
              for attr_name, method in t.__class__.__dict__.items()  
              if isinstance(method, property)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `dir`:

```py
a = Test()
dir(a)
```

Output:

```
['__doc__', '__module__', 'value']
```

So you could maybe do something like:

```py
d = {}
for attr in dir(a):
    if not attr.startswith("__"):
        d[attr] = getattr(a, attr)
```

Output:

```
d = {'value': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is even worse that that. You could imagine to build an instance `__dict__` at init time, but that would not solve anything, except for read_only constant properties. Because the value in the dict will be a copy of the property at the time it was taken, and will not reflect future changes.