# Converting dictionary with complex type to xml

Tags: python, xml

I have a dictionary called `job_highlight_dict` which contains `{job_id, JobHighlight}`

job_id is number and `JobHighlight` is a type as defined below:

```
class JobHighlight:
    def __init__(self, display_salary, location, category):
        self.display_salary = display_salary
        self.location = location
        self.category = category
```

I want to convert `job_highlight_dict` to xml and write it to disk, this is what I have tried:

```
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(self.job_highlight_dict)
file = open("export/path_%(time)s.xml", "wb")
file.write(xml)
file.close()
```

but I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Unsupported data type: <JobHighlight
> object at 0x000002D00FA48E88> (JobHighlight)

Answer (score 1):

You convert the `job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"]` from a `JobHighlight` type to a dictionary.

**Code**

```
job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"] = {
    "display_salary": job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"].display_salary,
    "location": job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"].location,
    "category": job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"].category
}
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(job_highlight_dict)
file = open("paths.xml", "wb")
file.write(xml)
file.close()
```

Or more simply:

```
job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"] = vars(job_highlight_dict["JobHighlight"])
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(job_highlight_dict)
file = open("paths.xml", "wb")
file.write(xml)
file.close()
```

See: [Python dictionary from an object's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

**Example of Output**

I formatted this, but in the file the xml will appear all on one line. If you want it formatted, you'll have to use pretty-printing or something of the like. See: https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <job_id type="int">2</job_id>
    <JobHighlight type="dict">
        <display_salary type="str">$80k</display_salary>
        <location type="str">Los Angeles</location>
        <category type="str">Other</category>
    </JobHighlight>
</root>
```