# How to get all values of variables in class?

Tags: python, class, variables, enums

```py
class NiceClass():
    some_value = SomeObject(...)
    some_other_value = SomeOtherObject(...)

    @classmethod
    def get_all_vars(cls):
        ...
```

**I want `get_all_vars()` to return `[SomeObject(...), SomeOtherObject(...)]`, or more specifically, the values of the variables in `cls`.**

Solutions tried that didn't work out for me:

- `return [cls.some_value, cls.some_other_value, ...]` (requires listing the variable manually)
- subclassing `Enum` then using `list(cls)` (requires using `some_value.value` to access the value elsewhere in the program, also type hinting would be a mess)
- namedtuples (nope not touching that subject, heard it was much more complicated than `Enum`)
- `[value for key, value in vars(cls).items() if not callable(value) and not key.startswith("__")]` (too hacky due to using `vars(cls)`, also for some reason it also includes `get_all_vars` due to it being a `classmethod`)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille not the answer that i was looking for, but it is a solution to my problem so uhh ??

would still like a solution to this question though

Comment: Using `isinstance(value, classmethod)` instead of `callable(value)` will remove `get_all_vars` from the list. It won't get less hacky though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. This is a straight answer to your question:

```py
class Foo:
    pass


class Bar:
    x: int = 1
    y: str = 'hello'
    z: Foo = Foo()

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        xs = []
        for name, value in vars(cls).items():
            if not (name.startswith('__') or isinstance(value, classmethod)):
                xs.append(value)
        return xs
```

---

This is what I suggest:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields


class Foo:
    pass


@dataclass
class Bar:
    x: int = 1
    y: str = 'hello'
    z: Foo = Foo()

    @classmethod
    def get_defaults(cls):
        return [f.default for f in fields(cls)]

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        return [getattr(cls, f.name) for f in fields(cls)]
```

results:

```
Bar.get_defaults() == Bar.get_all()
# True -> [1, 'hello', __main__.Foo]

Bar.x = 10
Bar.get_defaults() == Bar.get_all()
# False -> [1, 'hello', __main__.Foo] != [10, 'hello', __main__.Foo]
```

Comment: dataclass method works, the first one also somewhat works although it doesn't check for callables

Comment: @TNTzx I edited the `dataclass`. Please give it a check

Comment: got it, it works

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of values *and* define individual attributes at the same time with minimal boilerplate.

```
class NiceClass():
    (some_value,
     some_other_value,
    ) = _all_values = [
        SomeObject(...),
        SomeOtherObject(...)
    ]
    

    @classmethod
    def get_all_vars(cls):
        return cls._all_values
```

The most obvious drawback to this is that it's easy to get the order of names and values out of sync.

Ideally, you might like to do something like

```
class NiceClass:

    _attributes = {
        'some_value': SomeObject(...),
        'some_other_value': SomeOtherObject(...)
    }

    @classmethod
    def get_all_vars(cls):
        return cls._attributes.values()
```

and have some way to "inject" the contents of `_attributes` into the class namespace directly. The simplest way to do this is with a mix-in class that defines `__init_subclass__`:

```
class AddAttributes:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.__dict__.update(cls._attributes)


class NiceClass(AddAttributes):
    # As above
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

This might sound like a https://xyproblem.info/ but my solution might work in the other case as well. You can get the fields of an object by using `__dict__` or `vars` (which is considered more pythonic given: [Python dictionary from an object's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields))

You could do something like:

```
class ClassTest:
   def __init__(self):
      self.one = 1
      self.two = 2
list(vars(ClassTest()).values())
```

But you will see that it has some limitations. It doesn't recognize the not in `self.variable_name` defined variables like you have used above. It might help you nonetheless, because you can simply define them in init.

Comment: OP already knows about `vars` as a possible solution, and anyway this example does not reflect OP's usecase

Comment: You are right, but I am still unsure why this is too hacky. Therefore I thought it might help to give an example.

Comment: @Natan it's not hacky at all; Here's a part of `vars` documentation: `With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__`, which means that's exactly its intended use.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic I agree. The questioner doesn't.